# Categorical proof that having enough injectives implies existence of injective resolutions

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

The usual proof that a category with enough injectives also has injective resolutions for every object goes as follows: Fix an object $A$. Then there is a morphism $f^0:A\to I^0$ for some injective object $I^0$. There is an injective object $I^1$ admitting a monomorphism $\text{coker}f^0\to I^1$. Let $f^1$ be the composition $I^0\to\text{coker} f^0\to I^1$, and continue like so.

Exactness is of course clear in the case of modules: The map $I^0\to\text{coker} f^0$ is literally a quotient map whose kernel is exactly $\text{im} f^0$, and the injection $\text{coker} f^0\to I^1$ doesn't contribute anything to the kernel. But I'm having trouble proving exactness in a purely categorical manner (i.e., showing that $\ker(I^0\to\text{coker}f^0\to I^1)$ satisfies the universal property of $\text{im} f^0$, etc.).

Comment: The image is the kernel of the cokernel. Now try to show, using universal properties, that if you have $A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C$ such that $g$ is a monomorphism, then $\mathrm{Ker}(g \circ f)=\mathrm{Ker}(f)$

Comment: @LukasHeger Oh I see. I totally forgot that first fact!